# 1960s Sci-Fi/Horror Movie ID from Dramatic Final Scene

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie I'm searching for in this instance is likely an early 1960s sci-fi/horror piece. I can only recall the final dramatic ending scene of the movie, though I think someone will quickly recognize it.

The movie is in black and white with a typical suit-wearing, problem-solving hero who has cornered the villain/monster in a precarious position. The final scene takes place on a large water tower at night. The hero is hanging from the tower's ladder while fighting with the villains, both of whom are wearing masks either intended to hide their identity or that indicate their inner nature. Its not clear to me what happened to the villains, but shortly into this scene they lost their footing and fell off of the tower. What I recall specifically about this action was that the filming was zoomed in on the masks of each figure as they fell (separately) exaggerating their features and increasing the drama. A cut to a wide angle view of the long fall of each body followed, with a close shot of each body on the ground. The hero approached the larger body and pulled off its mask indicating the identity of the mad scientist or lead villain, as the movie concluded.

I may have started viewing this movie late in the action as I cannot seem to recall much else, though I suspect the above is enough for an ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was it a Mexican film involving wrestlers? If so, it might be *[Sex Monster](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056201/?ref_=tt_urv)*, aka *Doctor of Doom*, aka *Las luchadoras contra el médico asesino*, aka *Las Luchadoras in Wrestling Women vs The Aztec Ape*, a 1963 "Mexploitation" film involving luchador masks, mad scientists, and a monster.

[image: Doctor of Doom]

> A mad scientist terrorizes a city by kidnapping young women with his ape-man Gomar and then using them as subjects in sadistic brain transplant experiments. A female wrestler whose sister was one of the victims swears vengeance against the Mad Doctor.

*[Mexploitation Cinema](https://books.google.com/books?id=ci1zBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=film%20%22water%20tower%22%20masks&source=bl&ots=eU7iqUUBus&sig=OycELl6M4P21JstGBsLdg9kxMLA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiH3uS2zK_fAhVymeAKHTNUCosQ6AEwFnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=film%20%22water%20tower%22%20masks&f=false)* mentions the water-tower scene:

> Mike climbs up the water tower to confront the Mad Doctor and Vendetta "man to man," and "man to ape-man-woman," respectively. Tommy, demonstrating surprising and considerable marksmanship, shoots both villains from his vantage point on the ground, sending them plummeting to their deaths. Professor Wright is finally unmasked by Mike, who carries the mask like a trophy, again recalling the symbolics of lucha libre rather than the horror film. By unmasking the villain, Mike achieves masculine mastery over him, and he holds the mask as if it were an emasculated opponent's severed penis.

I found this book on the second page of a search for *film "water tower" masks*

I believe this is a trailer:

[Here is another page](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~dwilt/luchamed.htm) specifically about this movie:

> However, Ruiz survives and transplants Gomar's brain into a woman wrestler's body; he names the resulting creation "Vendetta" (since Gomar is male, this is actually a sort of sex-change operation for him). Vendetta wrestles Gloria and is gaining the upper hand, when Rubí spots Marcado, one of Ruiz's henchmen, in the arena. Marcado, under pressure, admits Vendetta's masked manager is really the scarred Ruiz. The police are alerted, and Vendetta and Ruiz flee to the top of a nearby tower. Armando climbs up in pursuit, but is nearly killed; Chema shoots and kills Ruiz and Vendetta.

Comment: That's it. The end of the movie was exactly what I recalled, though I was not expecting it to be a Mexican movie. I'm now going to look through some lists of Mexican sci-fi and horror to see if the termite-creature movie I'm looking for might be Mexican. Thank you.